# Using DRF serializer to add custom details to multiple models

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

### EDIT (adding actual models and details)

**

Okay so the question is going to be a bit lengthy and there are actually four models. Whenever I create an invoice, I need to add invoice detail that comes from the frontend for which I use a loop and add all that to my database. The next part is to create a record in the **Ledger** table and **ProductQuantity** table too for which I have to repeat the code that I have written in **InvoiceCreateAndGetByIdOnly**. I have many views that are updating multiple models and I am repeating a lot of code. As you can see the **serializers.py** is very thin and **views.py** is pretty thick. Just like ***InvoiceCreate*** view, I have other views that update **Ledger** and **ProductQuantity** model so I have to redo everything in my **views.py** again and again

---

### models.py

```
class Invoice(models.Model):

    invoice_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date(datetime.now()))
    builty_num = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    total_amount = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])
    discount = models.FloatField(default=0.0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])
    overflow = models.FloatField(default=0.0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])


class InvoiceDetail(models.Model):

    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rate = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])
    num_thaan = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    gazaana_per_thaan = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])


class Ledger(models.Model):
    TYPE = (
    ('D','Debit'),
    ('C','Credit'),
    )

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    return_invoice = models.ForeignKey(ReturnInvoice, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cash = models.ForeignKey(CashDetail, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cheque = models.ForeignKey(ChequeDetail, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cheque_transfer = models.ForeignKey(ChequeTransfer, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bank = models.ForeignKey(BankTransfer, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date(datetime.now()))
    detail = models.TextField()
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE)
    amount = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])
    balance = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])
    balance_status = models.CharField(max_length=6)


class ProductQuantity(models.Model):

    TYPE = (
    ('+','Add'),
    ('-','Subtract'),
    )    

    invoice_id_add = models.ForeignKey(StockInvoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    invoice_id_sub = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    invoice_id_return = models.ForeignKey(ReturnInvoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    invoice_id_stock_return = models.ForeignKey(StockReturnInvoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey(Warehouse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date(datetime.now()))
    num_thaan = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    rate = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])
    gazaana_per_thaan = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])
    quantity = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])
    transaction_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE)
```

---

### views.py

```
class InvoiceCreateAndGetByIdOnly(APIView):
    """
    only handle post/get request when the invoice is created, 
    update ledger accordingly and updates quantity in ProductQuantity
    """

    permission_classes = [canEditInvoice]

    def get(self, request):
        if 'invoice_id' in request.query_params:
            query = Invoice.objects.filter(
                invoice_id = request.query_params['invoice_id']
                )
            return Response(InvoiceSerializer(query,many=True).data)
        query = Invoice.objects.all()
        return Response(InvoiceSerializer(query, many=True).data)


    def post(self, request):
        allData = request.data
        data = request.data
        invoice_detail = data.pop('invoice_set')
        serializer_invoice = InvoiceSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer_invoice.is_valid():

            invoice = serializer_invoice.create(
                validated_data=serializer_invoice.validated_data
                )
           
            invoice_detail_array = []
            """adding invoice_id to the invoice_detail_set"""
            for detail in invoice_detail:
                isValid = False
                detail['invoice'] = invoice.invoice_id
                invoice_detail_array.append(detail)
                serializer_new = InvoiceDetailSerializer(data=detail) 

                if serializer_new.is_valid(): 
                    isValid = True
                else: 
                    Invoice.objects.filter(invoice_id=invoice.invoice_id).delete()
                    return Response(
                        serializer_new.errors, 
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                        )

            for detail in invoice_detail_array:
                quantity , thaan = ProductQuantity.get_quantity(
                    product=detail['product'], 
                    warehouse=detail['warehouse'],
                    gazaana=detail['gazaana_per_thaan']
                    )
                if(thaan < detail['num_thaan']):
                    Invoice.objects.filter(invoice_id=invoice.invoice_id).delete()
                    return Response(
                        {'error':'less thaan in stock'}, 
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                        )
                if(quantity < (detail['num_thaan'] * detail['gazaana_per_thaan'])):
                    Invoice.objects.filter(invoice_id=invoice.invoice_id).delete()
                    return Response(
                        {'error':'less quantity in stock'}, 
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                        )

                quantity = {
                    'invoice_id_sub' : invoice.invoice_id,
                    'product': detail['product'],
                    'warehouse': detail['warehouse'],
                    'date': invoice.date,
                    'num_thaan': detail['num_thaan'],
                    'rate': detail['rate'],
                    'quantity': detail['num_thaan'] * detail['gazaana_per_thaan'],
                    'gazaana_per_thaan': detail['gazaana_per_thaan'],
                    'transaction_type': '-'
                }    

                serializer_new = InvoiceDetailSerializer(data=detail)
                serializer_product_quantity = ProductQuantitySerializer(data=quantity)
                if(serializer_new.is_valid()):
                    invoice_detail = serializer_new.create(
                        validated_data=serializer_new.validated_data
                        )
                    if(serializer_product_quantity.is_valid()):
                        product_quantity_detail = serializer_product_quantity.create(
                            validated_data=serializer_product_quantity.validated_data)
         
            
            invoice_db = Invoice.objects.get(invoice_id=invoice.invoice_id)
            invoice_detail_db = InvoiceDetail.objects.all().filter(invoice=invoice_db.invoice_id)
            detail = " "
            for obj in invoice_detail_db:
                detail += (
                    str(obj.num_thaan) + " thaan " + 
                    str(obj.gazaana_per_thaan) + " gaz " + 
                    str(obj.product) + " @ PKR " + 
                    str(obj.rate) + "\n"
                    )

            balance = Ledger.get_balance(invoice_db.customer.customer_id)
            new_balance = balance -  invoice_db.total_amount - invoice_db.overflow + invoice_db.discount
            status_ledger = ""
            if( new_balance == 0):
                status_ledger = "Nill"
            elif( new_balance > 0):
                status_ledger = "Credit"
            elif( new_balance < 0):
                status_ledger = "Debit"

            data_ledger = {
                'customer': invoice_db.customer.customer_id,
                'invoice' : invoice_db.invoice_id,
                'date' : invoice_db.date,
                'transaction_type' : 'D',
                'amount' : invoice_db.total_amount + invoice_db.overflow - invoice_db.discount ,
                'detail' : detail,
                'balance': abs(new_balance),
                'balance_status': status_ledger,
            }
            
            serializer_ledger = LedgerSerializer(data=data_ledger)
            if serializer_ledger.is_valid():
                ledger_instance = serializer_ledger.create(
                    validated_data=serializer_ledger.validated_data
                    )
            else:
                return Response(
                    serializer_ledger.errors, 
                    status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                    )

            return Response({
                "message":"invoice successfully created",
                "data":allData
                }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(
            serializer_invoice.errors, 
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
```

---

### serializers.py

```
class LedgerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Ledger
        fields = '__all__'


class InvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    invoice_detail = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_invoice_details')

    def get_invoice_details(self,obj):
        return InvoiceDetailSerializer(InvoiceDetail.objects.filter(invoice=obj),many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice
        # fields = '__all__'
        fields = ['invoice_detail', 'customer', 'builty_num','date', 'total_amount', 'invoice_id', 'overflow', 'discount']


class InvoiceDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceDetail
        fields = '__all__'


class ProductQuantitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductQuantity
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Can you give a concrete example ? It's not clear what the question is and what you expect.

Comment: @BriseBalloches, I just updated the question and added all the details, if you require more details please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you should use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/) to modify C when A, B, is changed like following

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

class A(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class B(models.Model):
    field1 = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field2 = models.FloatField()

class C(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    field2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)


def modify_c(a, b):
    c = C.objects.get() # get instance of C through C.object.get() using a, b
    # update c through fields of a and b
    c.save()

@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=A)
@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=B)
def update_c_from_a_or_b(sender, instance, *args, **keywords):
    if sender == A:
        instance_of_a = instance
        instance_of_b = # get instance of B through B.objects.get()
    if sender == B:
        instance_of_b = instance
        instance_of_a =  instance.field1 # ForeignKey key to A
    modify_c(instance_of_a, instance_of_b)
```

Comment: Hey, I have just updated my question. Can you have another look at it now? I think it wasn't very clear before. Thank you so much.